# Document automatically downloaded from SharePoint document library in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: document-library, browser-compatibility

I have a MS-word document in a library which gets downloaded automatically when I click over it. I am  using Google Chrome and Firefox.

It works fine when using Internet Explorer.

How can I avoid this issue in other browsers (Google Chrome and Firefox) while I have "Edit" permission for the documents

Any suggestion / solutions will be appreciated

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using? What is the behavior when you do it in IE?

From my experience, SharePoint doesn't play well with other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work with SP2010 and other browser than IE - just expand the item context menu and click Edit in Excel and you will get the error message (using Chrome/FF).

Example:
http://postimg.org/image/zg09pmo23/